# using ios device's local sources when developing a html application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, web

I want to develop an application which works on xcode's uiwebview. But I want to use local sources instead of internet sources. For example I want to import some photos into my project and build it with that photos. Then I want user to download them with the application (which makes sense) ***(My question is here! :)***  I want that application to use photos which are downloaded within the application.

I'm hopefull that I can do it with a path changing* trick. But I'm not sure if it's the same for all devices. And I'm not sure what I should write about path.

here is what I mean :

Is it possible?

If it's possible, how can I determine "PATH_OF_FOLDER_IN_IPHONE" path?

Thx for all suggestions & helpful answers.

Comment: IDK if Xcode has an UIWebView. Even if it had, how are you supposed to load an HTML page from your iPhone to Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Add the image as a resource to your project.

Let say the name of the image is footer.png, you get the path with the following code:

```
NSString *footerPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                    pathForResource:@"footer"
                                             ofType:@"png"];
NSURL *footerURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:footerPath];
```

You will then replace the source path of the image tag in the HTML file with the full path.

Comment: it looks really great and pretty easy. but... how can I replace the source path again? I mean, *footerURL will be in the device and that source of the tag will be recieved from internet. So how can I implement it? :S I'm really confused about it :/